# Number being returned as NaN after computation

Tags: javascript, numbers, coordinates, google-places-api, nan

I have this sequence of code:

```
  ...

  console.log(place.geometry.location.lat() + " lrdrdr " + place.geometry.location.lng());
  var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
  var lon = place.geometry.location.lng();

  write_points(lat, lon, const_lat, const_lon);
}

function write_points(starting_lat, starting_lon, constant_lat, constant_lon) {
  var counter = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    var starting_lon_var = starting_lon + constant_lon * (i * Math.random());
    console.log(starting_lat + " lahdeedah " + starting_lon_var);

    ...
```

This is the console output:

```
42.247865 lrdrdr -71.17272600000001
42.247865 lahdeedah NaN
```

Why is the value after `lrdrdr` (`-71.17272600000001`) becoming NaN in the `write_points` function that gets called. I pass it as a parameter (`starting_lon`) and it goes through this `starting_lon + constant_lon * (i * Math.random())` computation, then when that is output, it gives `NaN` for some reason.

Comment: Where have you defined `const_lon`?

Comment: i had that thought too finally and figured it out...it was the const_lon definition causing the problem

Comment: Glad for you mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Another case of checking all your variables - `const_lon` was being created as `NaN` because of another variable involved in its conputation.